# EF5 delete entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

How I can delete an entity using EF5? I'm getting this error:

```
The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager.
```

when I try to call .Remove on my DbSet. After googling I tried that

```
mycontext.Attach(entity)
mycontext.Remove(entity)
```

But in this way I get:

```
An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.
```

So, is it or not in ObjectStateManager?! :)

My entity is like that:

```
[Table("Words")]
public class Word : IWord
{
    [Key, Required]
    public int WordId { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(50)]
    public string Tag { get; set; }

    //Foreign Key
    public int VocabularyId { get; set; }

    //Navigation
    public virtual Vocabulary Vocabulary { get; set; }
    public virtual Language Language { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Translation> Translations { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider 2 scenario:

**1. Connected scenario:** you load the entity from database and mark it as deleted

```
var word = ctx.Words.Where(a=>a.WordId == wordId).First();
ctx.DeleteObject(word);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

**2. Disconnected scenario:** attach an existing entity and mark it as deleted

```
var word = new Word() { WordId = id };
ctx.Words.Attach(word);
ctx.DeleteObject(word);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

The second approach will help you avoid un-necessary database round trip

Comment: 1. works for me. Sincerely I don't understand why it should so complicated to delete an entity (I blame EF, not you :)) .. anyway, thank you very much